# Problem with reloaded data

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have a servlet which takes from jsp some data, and puts it in a file.
Another jsp is using this data.
I have a problem because my servlet uses an old file, despite changes.
This changes are invisible until i restart TomCat.
Is there any simple solution of this problem?

Comment: It is difficult to say without the code.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat - and many other servlet containers - caches compiled-JSPs.
Try one of following way:

1. Touch the JSP file, and make its last-modified timestamp newer than chache file's timestamp.
2. Delete cache file saved as "foobar.java" and "foobar.class" in Tomcat work directory.